# How do I use a dynamically declared variable in R ggplot when using count() and factor() functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to plot some relative frequency data using `ggplot` in a more efficient manner.

I have many variables of interest, and want to plot a separate barchart for each. The following is my current code for one variables of interest `Gender`:

```
chart.gender <- data %>% 
     count(Gender = factor(Gender)) %>% 
     mutate(Gender = fct_reorder(Gender,desc(n))) %>% 
     mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x=Gender, y=n, fill=Gender)) +
            geom_col()
```

This works, but the variable `Gender` is repeated many times. Since I need to repeat plots for many variables of interest (Gender, Age, Location, etc.) with similar code, I would like to simplify this by declaring the variable of interest once at the top and using that declared variable for the rest of the code. Intuitively, something like:

```
var <- "Gender"
chart.gender <- data %>% 
     count(var = factor(var)) %>% 
     mutate(var = fct_reorder(var,desc(n))) %>% 
     mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x=var, y=n, fill=var)) +
            geom_col()
```

Which does not result in a plot of three-level factor count of gender frequencies, but merely a single column named 'Gender'. I believe I see **why** it's not working, but I do not know the solution for it: I want R to retrieve the variable name I stored in `var`, and then use that to retrieve the data for that variable in 'data'.

With some research I've found suggestions like using `as.name(var)`, but there seems to (at the least) be a problem with declaring the variable `var` as a factor within the `count()` function.

Some reproducible data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(sample(c("Male", "Female", "Prefer not to say"),20,replace=TRUE))
colnames(data) <- c("Gender")
```

I'm using the following packages in R: `tidyverse`, `ggplot2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `as.name()` when you set the variable initially, you can use !! ("bang-bang") to unquote the variable for the `count()` step.

```
var <- as.name("Gender")

chart.gender <- data %>% 
     count(var = factor(!! var)) %>% 
     mutate(var = fct_reorder(var,desc(n))) %>% 
     mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x=var, y=n, fill=var)) +
     geom_col()
```

Comment: Thanks @stlba ! This does indeed solve the issue. Logically, ```ggplot``` now has fill-label and x-axis label as "var", would you be able to advise on a way that it shows "Gender"? Is there a more subtle way than ```labs(x=var,fill=var)```?

Comment: I would just use labs as you suggested, I'm not sure if there's a more straightforward way

Comment: If you're reusing this code for multiple variables, I'd save the code as a function so you only have to run `data %>% plot_vars("Gender")` or similar for each variable instead of copying and pasting the code. Having the extra line for `labs()` doesn't make much difference in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.data` pronound to subset the column with `var` as variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

var <- "Gender"
data %>% 
  count(var = factor(.data[[var]])) %>% 
  mutate(var = fct_reorder(var,desc(n))) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=var, y=n, fill=var)) +
  geom_col()
```

Or another way would be using `sym` and `!!`

```
data %>% 
  count(var = factor(!!sym(var))) %>% 
  mutate(var = fct_reorder(var,desc(n))) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=var, y=n, fill=var)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, that's a great solution!